# Is it possible to create a variable directly in Spark workers?

Tags: java, apache-spark

What I would like to do is generate a context inside every Spark worker that I can use for local look-ups. 
The look-up data is located in a database and I would like to cache it on every worker. Is there a simple way to do this?

Workarounds used:

1. Create a lazily initialized `Broadcast` variable and use it with my functions. The first time a function tries to access it, I call my SQL code to initialize it.
2. Create an eagerly initialized `Broadcast` and use torrent broadcasting to make it available in workers

PS. I did not use `JdbcRDD` because I want the data to be replicated rather than partitioned. Does anyone knows what would happen if I did not use the partitioning attributes of the `JdbcRDD`? Would that just make it work or would it have a non-deterministic behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a singleton object containing a reference to the resolution cache you want to use:

```
object ResolutionCache {
   var connection = _
   var cache: Map[Key,Value] = Map()
   def resolve(key:Key):Value = ???
}
```

Then this object can be used to resolve values in an RDD operation:

```
val resolved = keysRDD.map(key => (key -> ResolutionCache.resolve(key)))
```

The connections and values held by this object will be maintained independently per worker JVM.
We must take special care of the connection management and concurrent behavior. In particular, `resolve` must be thread-safe.

Comment: Can you please provide same solution using python ? Also since this answer seems to be old, is there any latest update with newer version to make the variables initialized once on all the workers?